# equal height bootstrap boxes in a loop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I struggle everytime I face this problem, and I haven't found a solution yet that makes my life easier. My layout is simple, 14 boxes side by side. I'm using `col-sm-12` class (my bootstrap is configured to have 24 columns) on the boxes. but the content inside the boxes vary, so their heights are not equal, and bigger boxes "push" the box immediately after those. Pretty straightforward solution is to use a row after every two box, but here's the catch, the boxes are generated by a loop! I can set a `min-height` but that does not look pretty on mobile (too much space on landscape). I'm not sure about browser support for `flexbox`.

is there any other hacks that I might use?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-xs-24 col-sm-12 col-md-12 blocks"><!--the loop starts from here-->
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8"> some content</div>
       <div class="col-sm-16">some more content that changes height. you can put some lorem isum in here. </div>
    </div>
    <!--my loop, aka, blocks, end here-->
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: set max height and min height property to your required height, then if needed add overflow scroll or something incase you need to see the data

Comment: I mentioned already that setting height doesn't work, because there's lots of blank space in mobile, and I am not sure how much height it needs, because the content is dynamic. setting `overflow:scroll` will also look horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not sure about using `flexbox` because doesnt support IE10 and below you can use CSS tables

Note that I use the standard 12 columns for the demo.

```css
.blocks > .row {
  display: table
}
.blocks .row > [class*="col"] {
  display: table-cell;
  background: red;
  float:none /* override the float:left from bootstrap.css */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 blocks">
      <!--the loop starts from here-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">some content</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">some more content that changes height. you can put some lorem isum in here.</div>
      </div>
      <!--my loop, aka, blocks, end here-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED** as per request of OP in comments below

Here is a another version using CSS tables as well, but due to be on the loop OP can't add HTML markup.

So a simpler way given the markup is clearing left at each 4 item

```css
.row{
  margin:15px auto;
}
.block{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid white;
  padding:15px 5px;
}
.block h4{
  color: pink; 
  text-decoration:underline;
}

.block:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  clear:left
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>this is a small paragraph</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>this is another small paragraph</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>wow! small paragraph</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>again small paragraph!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>Now we get a big one!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur imperdiet, leo vitae accumsan lobortis, ligula mauris pretium turpis, a feugiat ligula ex sit amet tortor. In tempor, purus id faucibus laoreet, nisi risus volutpat justo, id finibus ligula magna id libero. Nunc orci tellus, consequat vitae nibh vel, fermentum aliquet ex. Integer laoreet rhoncus leo nec ultricies. Nam feugiat quam nec odio interdum dignissim.  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>Lets add more small paragraphs</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>again small paragraph no 2!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>And this is small paragraph no 3!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <!--lets assume this coloumn is on the loop-->
      <h4>And this is small paragraph no 4!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet tortor pretium quam dapibus maximus nec quis dolor. Mauris non auctor eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm now looking at css tables. Didn't want to use it at first because it is obviously not tabular data, but when life gives you lemons, you have to make lemonade! :(

Comment: you have more options [here](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) still this is by far the simplest (excluding `flexbox`) that you don't want to use

Comment: @SamiaRuponti did you look at the options I gave you in my above comment?

Comment: Sorry, I got busy with something else. I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: I tested it, but it is not working.I have lots of divs, and making the children display as `table-cell` makes them all appear side by side. In effect, I get a table that has a huge `overflow-x`. I may just have to put `min-height` after all.

Comment: sorry, localhost! I'll create a codepen in the evening. thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a sample pen I made. http://codepen.io/samia92/pen/QEjdGv I want the div's to be in their natural order - with equal height. Can you please edit this?

Comment: @SamiaRuponti sorry for late reply, here is [Table Layout Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEeXrG), and as last resort, even if you don't want to use, [Flex Layout CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzoYQE)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pens. I just looked at the table layout codepen, and I see that you put a row after every three elements. Herein lies my problem, all my columns are in a `twig` loop. I really can't insert rows there, even with jquery, because the layout is not the same in every break point. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Not the best I know, but here is a [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKmvXQ) that might help you, without messing with  the loop, giving IE9+ support (no flexbox) , regarding your question, see flexbox support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: This works pretty good! Such a simple solution, it didn't even occur to me! and with bootstrap's media queries,I can control mobile layouts easily too! thanks a lot. If you add this to your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`flex` is your solution here, really - when it comes to columns/boxes of equal height: `flex` it - and let the browser do the calculations and all the "heavy lifting".

```css
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-row div[class*="col-sm"] {
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 0 1 45%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class=" col-xs-24 col-sm-12 col-md-12 blocks"><!--the loop starts from here-->
   <div class="row flex-row">
      <div class="col-sm-8"> some content</div>
       <div class="col-sm-16">some more content that changes height. you can put some lorem isum in here. </div>
    </div>
    <!--my loop, aka, blocks, end here-->
   </div>
 </div>
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMwXZq)

**Support**

As far as browser support goes, `flex` is generally well supported these days - aside from Safari browsers - despite what [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) says about it.

Otherwise, no support for IE 8 or 9 (but no surprise there either really), IE 10 supports an older version of the syntax (from 2011) and there's partial support for IE 11.
There are older webkit browsers (Firefox & Safari) that support an even older version of the syntax (from 2009) - you'll need fallback rules for these browsers that support Flexbox legacy (e.g: 2009 syntax, 2011 hybrid syntax and browser prefixes).

[Advanced Cross-browser Flexbox](https://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/)

But if you're adamant about avoiding `flex` then you'll have to settle with tables, or let go of the idea of equal-height columns and stick with generic `inline-block` elements.

Comment: OP stated that doesn't want to use `flexbox` due to not support all the browsers she might need to support. *I'm not sure about browser support for `flexbox, `is there any other hacks that I might use?*

Comment: @dippas That's why a link was included to address cross-browser support. A potential solution shouldn't be avoided just because of one's lack of knowledge on the subject, but should rather be interpreted as an opportunity to familiarize one's self on said subject. Furthermore, `flex` is a solution that others who share the same problem may find useful. Answers shouldn't only address the OP immediate problem but should provide solutions for the community as a whole.

Comment: I'd love to use `flex` (seriously), but unfortunately, I have to support IE9! +1 for a very well described answer though.

Comment: BTW, how's mobile browser support for `flex`? @dippas